# ImageResizer .eps support

Tags: imageresizer

Is it possible to server .eps image with ImageResizer? For example by automatically converting them to .png. I'm looking for something which works as the [PdfRenderer plug in](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/pdfrenderer), but for .eps Image.

When I use the RemoteReader plugin to reference a .eps file ImageResizer throws an exception with the message:

"File may be corrupted, empty, or may contain a PNG image with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageResizer doesn't support .eps, but Ghostscript does, which underlies PdfRenderer. I suggest modifying/forking PdfRenderer to introduce .eps support.

We don't have any plans to support this officially, but we would certainly merge a pull request that added the functionality to PdfRenderer.

Most of our efforts going forward (re: pdf) will be on [PdfiumRenderer](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/pdfiumrenderer), which has better characteristics.